# redirect with htaccess to * page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i'm using a directory named "onedrive/example/"
In the dir Example all my php files are stored.

Now i want to redirect using htaccess like this:

When someone is trying to access http://www.my-site.com/onedrive-redirect/pagename.php htaccess needs to redirect the user to http://www.my-site.com/onedrivee/example/pagename.php

But how do i create that? I already tryed this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

php_flag session.bug_compat_42 0
php_flag session.bug_compat_warn 0

php_value memory_limit 64M

RewriteRule ^onedrive-redirect/(.*)/ ./onedrive/example/$1.php
RewriteRule ^onedrive-redirect/(.*) ./onedrive/example/$1.php
```

but this example doesn't do the job for me. Can someone help me to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file (**parent directory of `onedrive`**) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^onedrive-redirect(/.*)$ /onedrive/example$1 [L,NC]
```